# Using referenced complex types in WCF clients

Tags: c#, wcf, interface, datacontract

I'm kinda new to C#, and I've got a problem with a DataMember in a WCF application:

The DataMember in question is a List of instances of a class implementing an interface, let's call this class "classA", in "assemblyA", implementing "interfaceA".

The "main" data object (that has this DataMember) which is passed from server to client via WCF is defined as "classB" and lies in assembly "assemblyB" which is referenced in both server and client.

AssemblyB *has* a refence to assemblyA. All is fine so far.

Now the client (in "assemblyC") connects to the service that passes assemblyB DataContract objects via WCF, but asseblyC has NO reference to assemblyA (and shouldn't have!). All is still fine, serialization and deserialization work fine, but:

As soon as I try to *use* classA objects in assemblyC, C# complains it doesn't know the type.

Is there any way to import interfaceA into assemblyC without referencing assemblyA? I tried definining an interface in C that inherits from intefaceA ("interfaceCA") and cast to that in assemblyC… but no luck, C# still complains about the missing reference to assemblyA.

I can't move interfaceA from assemblyA to assemblyB, since assemblyA has to work without a reference to assemblyB, and I don't want to reference assemblyA in assemblyC, because assemblyC is not even supposed to know about assemblyA… apart from that one Data member.
And as far as I know, in C# I can't forcibly cast to a **copy** of interfaceA defined in assemblyB… so, anyone an idea how I can get it over to assemblyC?

Let's give you a simple pseudo code snippet for demonstration purposes:

```cs
// assemblyA

public interface iA
{
    string Stuff { get; }
}

[DataContract]
public class A : iA
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Stuff { get { return "Stuff"; } }
}
```

```cs
// assemblyB, references assemblyA

[DataContract]
public class B
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Num { get; protected set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<A> StuffContainers { get; protected set; }
}
```

```cs
// assemblyC, references assemblyB

public class C
{
    public void ReceiveData(B data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data.Num); // all fine

        // the following line shows an error
        foreach (var stuffContainer in data.StuffContainers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stuffContainer.Stuff);
        }

        // same here, of course since C# can't resolve namespaceA and/or iA
        foreach (namespaceA.iA stuffContainer in data.StuffContainers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stuffContainer.Stuff);
        }

        // same here of course
        List<namespaceA.iA> sC = (List<namespaceA.iA>)data.StuffContainers;
        foreach (namespaceA.iA stuffContainer in sC)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stuffContainer.Stuff);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this makes it clear enough… it's my first own SO question ever! ;)

Comment: Your data contract exposes `A` type, defined in assembly A, so it should be available to the client. I'd suggest to move all data contracts that are shared by the client and the service to separate shared assembly.

Comment: @stop-cran That would be my last resort, but it is of course a valid solution (in fact, I'd probably define a new equivalent interface and class in the shared assembly then, and implement a conversion operator between A and the new class definition, since assemblyA uses iA and A inside, but shouldn't have access to the other data types defined in assemblyB). I just hoped there was a way to expose/export/share the interface definition iA without that.

Comment: You can inherit class `A` (which you do not want to share) from a shared data contract and then employ `ServiceKnownType` attribute or `DataContractResolver` to correctly serialize A as its base class.